# How to apply specific torque to configurable joint in Unity

Tags: unity, torque, physx

I have a torque vector that needs to be applied to a configurable joint connecting two rigid bodies. This joint configured in such a way, that it only allows angular motion around all 3 axes.

Is there any way to apply torque vector to configurable joint?

PS: I'm using PhysX engine embedded in Unity, so I don't have access to D6 joint directly, but only through "configurable joint" wrapper. It combines Y and Z drives into one "YZ drive" for some reason, and I can't specify torques for Y and Z axes independently.